# Run Linux graphical program only on first login of the day

Tags: linux, x11, autostart

I want to set up my system to run Thunderbird (which needs x11) at the first login every day (so if I reboot on the same day, it wouldn't run). How do I go about setting this up?

---

The easiest way to start Thunderbird for me would be with `.xinitrc` but I'm not aware of a clean way to restrict it to only running once per day.

The way I could do this is to compare today's date to the last boot time (before this one), but I'm not aware of a standarized way to this, so I'm asking this question instead to avoid the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/497173/how-to-run-thunderbird-on-startup-minimised

Comment: @user1929959 I know how to run it at startup - `.xinitrc` will do just fine. The bigger problem I'm having is how to only do it once per day.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to detect if the service is already running and then restart it if necessary, rather than doing this "once a day" thing? I mean, what if you have to hard reboot your machine half way through the day?

Comment: @GemTaylor That would definitely be better if the program were a service, however I am trying to run Thunderbird (which is a mail client) and therefore **don't** want it to run again if I hard reboot the machine, as I've presumably already had a look at my mail.

Comment: Ok fair enough :-) Sorry still don't have an answer to the question :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't end up finding an idiomatic way to get the last boot date so I decided to store them in a custom file instead by using `/etc/rc.local` (which is executed at startup on my system) like so:

```
# Save boot time
date +%s >> /var/log/bootdate
```

I can then use this file within `.xinitrc` to start Thunderbird only if the day of the last boot is not today (i.e. this is the first boot of the day):

```
lastboot="$(date +%D -d@"$(tail -2 </var/log/bootdate | head -1)")"
today="$(date +%D)"
if [ "$today" != "$lastboot" ]; then
    # Run given programs only on the first boot of the day
    thunderbird &
fi
```